# Dispatch React Context API actions one after other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

By default react automatically manages which dispatches are needed to be executed together. So if 2 dispatches are written together, react will execute both and then make changes to the state. For example in the code below, there are two dispatches and the **nextPlayer** dispatch depends on the state changes from the first **HOLD_SCORE** dispatch. But react first executes both and then make changes to the state.

```js
  const holdScore = () => {
    dispatch({ type: HOLD_SCORE });
    checkWinner();
    nextPlayer();
  };

  const nextPlayer = () => {
    if (state.winner < 0) dispatch({ type: NEXT_PLAYER });
  };
```

I want **HOLD_SCORE** dispatch to make changes to the state and then **nextPlayer** to happen. Here's my reducer code:

```js
export default function (state, { type, payload }) {
  const activePlayer = state.players.find(
    (player) => player.id === state.activePlayer
  );

  const totalPlayers = state.players.length;

  switch (type) {
    case SET_DICE:
      return { ...state, dice: payload };
    case ADD_CURRENT_SCORE:
      activePlayer.currentScore += state.dice;

      return { ...state };
    case HOLD_SCORE:
      activePlayer.totalScore += activePlayer.currentScore;
      activePlayer.currentScore = 0;

      return { ...state };
    case NEXT_PLAYER:
      const nextPlayer =
        activePlayer.id < totalPlayers - 1 ? state.activePlayer + 1 : 0;

      return { ...state, activePlayer: nextPlayer };
    case SET_WINNER:
      if (activePlayer.totalScore >= state.scoreLimit)
        return { ...state, winner: activePlayer.id };
      else return { ...state };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: why not handle that type of logic in the reducer?

Comment: I can't get to know how can I do that, I've added my reducer code in the question. Lemme know If you see how can I handle this.

Comment: can you post your `checkWinner()` function as well?

Comment: `checkWinner()` just dispatches the action with type `SET_WINNER` and does nothing else

Comment: so what you're saying is you want to dispatch `HOLD_SCORE` then `SET_WINNER` then `NEXT_PLAYER` with a conditional, but you've broken this up into separate functions? I'm suggesting to make that entire flow one action. you can always reuse bits of code inside your reducer

Comment: That could work! but I want to know is there any way to not let react combine dispatches?

Comment: the thing is that state changes are asynchronous, so as you see state changes in a single event loop are batched. if you want to do something as a result of some previous state changing you need to `useEffect` and listen for the state change, though that's hacky in your case because you don't need to wait for the previous state to change in order to figure out your future state. it's all there in your reducer already